# JavaScript: How to know if a connection with a shared worker is still alive?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, webkit, web-worker

I'm trying to use a shared worker to maintain a list of all the windows/tabs of a web application. Therefore following code is used:

```
//lives in shared-worker.js
var connections=[];//this represents the list of all windows/tabs
onconnect=function(e){
  connections.push(e.ports[0]);
};
```

Everytime a window is created a connection is established with the `shared-worker.js` worker and the worker adds the connection with the window to the `connections` list.

When a user closes a window its connection with the shared worker expires and should be removed from the `connections` variable. But I don't find any reliable way to do that.

Looking at the [specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html) the objects of the `connections` variable doesn't seem to hold a property/function to check if the connection is still alive.

Is it possible?
Again, the overall goal is to have the list of all windows/tabs.

**EDIT:** An approach would be to make the shared worker message the windows and expect a reply. If the shared worker doesn't receive a reply then it would assume that the window is closed. In my experiments this approach has not shown to be reliable; the problem being that there is no way to tell if a window is closed or is just taking a long time to reply.

Comment: Don't the `MessagePort`s have an `onclose` handler? Let me check this in the spec.

Comment: Looks like there is: http://doc.wakanda.org/SharedWorker.301-688965.en.html

There is a case for 'disconnect'.

Comment: maybe you could ping the connections, lets say ever 2 seconds?

Comment: @dumbmatter _"Everytime a window is created a connection is established with the `shared-worker.js` worker"_ How is `window` created?

Answer (score 21):

This is only as reliable as beforeunload, but seems to work (tested in Firefox and Chrome). I definitely favour it over a polling solution.

```
// Tell the SharedWorker we're closing
addEventListener( 'beforeunload', function()
{
    port.postMessage( {command:'closing'} );
});
```

Then handle the cleanup of the port object in the SharedWorker.

```
e.ports[0].onmessage = function( e )
{
    const port = this,
    data = e.data;

    switch( data.command )
    {
        // Tab closed, remove port
        case 'closing': myConnections.splice( myConnections.indexOf( port ), 1 );
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in the case that the tab is abruptly finished. E.g. if the tab crashes or the user ends the tab's process.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the "unload" event for this, rather than "beforeunload"?  The whole point of having both is that a "beforeunload" handler can *prevent* the unload from occurring (if it's happening due to navigating away).  So if your handler runs before another one that prevents the page from closing, you'll end up with an open page that has been incorrectly removed from the shared worker's connections list!

Comment: Please look at my answer, maybe it could be a better alternative :)

Comment: @Doin As far as `unload` is concerned, you should not use it, because browser won't handle it well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

Comment: @DarkTrick, Egad! You're right!  `unload` is deprecated... but my objection to `beforeunload` is still valid.  So instead, the events I'd recommend using are `pagehide` and the corresponding `pageshow` (which is called if the page is resurrected from the history cache).

Comment: If you reload the page really fast repeatedly, the browser won't have time to execute the beforeunload function.

Answer (score 13):

I have been neck deep in the documentation all week working around the same problem.

The problem is the MessagePort specification.  The bad news being that it has no error handling, and no flag, method or event to determine whether it has been closed.

The good news is I have created a viable solution, but it's a lot of code.

Keep in mind even among the supporting browsers the activity is handled differently.  For example Opera will throw an error if you attempt to message or close a closed port.  The bad news is you have to use a try-catch to handle the error, the good news is you can use that feedback to close a port on at least one-side.

Chrome and Safari fail silently leaving you no feedback and no way to end invalid objects.

---

My solution involves delivery confirmation or a custom "callback" approach.  You use a setTimeout and pass the ID for it to the SharedWorker with your command, and before processing the command it sends back a confirmation to cancel the timeout.  That timeout is generally hooked to a closeConnection() method.

This takes a reactive approach instead of a pre-emptive, originally I toyed with using the TCP/IP protocol model but that involved creating more functions to handle each process.

---

Some Psuedo-Code as an example:

### Client/Tab Code:

```
function customClose() {
    try {
        worker.port.close();
    } catch (err) { /* For Opera */ }
}
function send() {
    try {
        worker.port.postMessage({command: "doSomething", content: "some Data", id: setTimeout(function() { customClose(); ); }, 1000);
    } catch (err) { /* For Opera */ }
}
```

### Thread/Worker Code:

```
function respond(p, d) {
    p.postMessage({ command: "confirmation", id: d.id });
}
function message(e) {// Attached to all ports onmessage
    if (e.data.id) respond(this, e.data);
    if (e.data.command) e.data.command(p, e.data);// Execute command if it exists passing context and content
}
```

I have placed a complete demonstration here:
http://www.cdelorme.com/SharedWorker/

I am new to stack overflow, so I am not familiar with how they handle large code posts, but my full solution is two 150 line files.

---

Just using delivery confirmation alone is not perfect, so I have worked at improving it by adding additional components.

In particular I was investigating this for a ChatBox system, so I wanted to use EventSource (SSE), XHR, and WebSockets, only XHR is supported inside SharedWorker objects supposedly, which creates a limitation if I wanted to have the SharedWorker do all the server communication.

Plus since it needs to work for browsers without SharedWorker support I would be creating long-hand duplicate processing inside the SharedWorker which doesn't make a lot of sense.

So in the end if I implement SharedWorker it would be as a communication channel for the open tabs only, and one tab will be the Control Tab.

If the control tab is closed, the SharedWorker won't know, so I added a setInterval to the SharedWorker to send an empty response request every few seconds to all open ports.  This allows Chrome and Safari to eliminate closed connections when no messages are being processed, and allows the control tab to change.

However, this also means if the SharedWorker process dies the tabs must have an interval to check in with the SharedWorker using the same approach every so often, allowing them to use the fallback approach of every-tab-for-themeselves that is inherent to all other browsers using the same code.

---

So, as you can see a combination of callbacks for delivery confirmation, setTimeout and setInterval must be used from both ends to maintain knowledge of connectivity.  It can be done but it's a giant pain in the rear.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one looking for a solution. I tried the "ping-message" approach too but it didn't seem to be reliable; there is no way to tell if a tab is closed and therefore doesn't respond or if this tab is just taking a long time to respond.

Comment: Yeah, I also had a look at the spec. Seems they have removed the `close` event, at least there was one [back in 2009](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-workers-20090423/#handler-workerglobalscope-onclose)

Comment: I think the best way currently is just to have a two-way callback that auto-closes unless the tab/worker responds.  Assuming you have a backup implementation of whatever you were using the SharedWorker for.  Not ideal, but functional.

Comment: "this also means if the SharedWorker process dies...".  @CDeLorme, I don't really get this.  Under what circumstances would the SharedWorker process die, while any window still holding a reference to it remains alive?  Can you kill the SharedWorker thread via (say) Windows Task Manager, without killing the browser windows themselves?

Answer (score 3):

So there is actually a way to work out, what ports are still alive and whose are not. The key to the success is `WeakRef` and the part of ["ports and garbage collection"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#ports-and-garbage-collection) portion of HTML standard, that cites how garbage collection work with `MessagePort`s.

The full code is here: https://gist.github.com/Akxe/b4cfefa0086f9a995a3578818af63ad9

The class is meant to be extendable to accommodate most use cases.

### `PortAwareSharedWorker`

The `PortAwareSharedWorker` is a singleton that checks the `alive` (more below) status of each of its connected ports. It also exposes `getOpenPorts` method that contains, all current "alive" ports.

### `PortAwareSharedWorkerPort` as replacement for `MessagePort`

The `MessagePort` is never exposed to the user. Instead, a wrapper with a weak reference is. It checks the validity of its reference with every action and handles edge some cases.

### Caveats

The solution is not bulletproof. Weak references are resolvable even after the port should have been closed (no way around it). To mitigate this the `PortAwareSharedWorkerPort` wrapper is provided, it will handle things like calling `postMessage` to an already closed port as it crashes in some browsers.

Also, the most noticeable, the spec states the following:

> Furthermore, a MessagePort object must not be garbage collected while there exists an event referenced by a task in a task queue that is to be dispatched on that MessagePort object, or while the MessagePort object's port message queue is enabled and not empty.

I am not 100% sure of the meaning of the quote, but my takeaway is that if within the `onmessage` callback the developer creates a long-running task that would result in further interaction with the port, the port cannot be closed. Ex.: Message comes in, a fetch request is made, and after it returns a response is sent back. During the time that the fetch is being requested/processed, the port cannot be collected.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think that wrapping the message port in the `WeakRef`erence is enough to make it collectable again.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use your code solution? Normally, you would have something á la `new SharedWorker('./sharedWorker.js')`. What exactly would you have to do to use your solution?

Comment: An example of how to use it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Stonetip there is a link with full working code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

`PortCollection` would come in handy but doesn't seem to be implemented in any browser.

> It acts as an opaque array of MessagePort objects, thus allowing the objects to be garbage collected when they stop being relevant, while still allowing scripts to iterate over the MessagePort objects.

source; http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html#portcollection

Edit; just rised an Issue for Chrome; http://crbug.com/263356

Comment: it acts like WeakValueMap

Comment: The specification dropped it.

Comment: I tried to mimic the PortCollection, please take a look on my answer

Answer (score 0):

...How about using the approach you suggest in the edit, i.e. use a keep-alive ping, BUT:

**Just before closing any unresponsive connection, send a "please reconnect" message through it, so that if a window isn't really closed, just busy, it'll know it has to re-connect?**

This technique should probably be combined with sending explicit "I'm closing now" messages from window onunload events, as per @Adria 's solution, so that normal window termination is handled efficiently and without any delay.

This is still *somewhat* unreliable, in that very busy windows might drop off the SharedWorker's list temporarily, before later re-connecting... but actually I don't see how you could do much better:  Consider that if a window hangs, practically speaking that's not going to be differentiable from a it being "busy" for some indefinitely long time, so you can't really catch one without catching the other (in any finite time, anyway).

Depending on your application, having very busy windows temporarily getting de-listed may or may not be a big problem.

Note that the keep-alive pings should be sent from the SharedWorker to windows, which should then respond:  If you try simply using setTimout() in the windows, you run into the problem that setTimeout() on *background* windows can be long delayed (up to 1 second on current browsers I believe), while the SharedWorker's setTimeout()s should run on schedule (give or take a few ms), and idling background windows will wake up and respond immediately to posted SharedWorker messages.

---

Here's a neat little demo of this technique, that:

1. Assigns each window a unique numerical ID
2. Keeps track of a single "active" window
3. Keeps track of the list of current window IDs, and the total count
4. Keeps all windows apprised of all the above at all times

**sharedworker.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Shared Worker Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sharedworker-host.js" async></script>
  <script>
    function windowConnected(init){ if (init) { document.title = "#"+thisWindowID; document.getElementById("idSpan").textContent = thisWindowID; } document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"; }
    function windowDisconnected(){ document.title = "#"+thisWindowID; document.body.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; }
    function activeWindowChanged(){ document.getElementById("activeSpan").textContent = activeWindowID; document.title = "#"+thisWindowID+(windowIsActive?" [ACTIVE]":""); document.body.style.backgroundColor = (windowIsActive?"pink":"lightgreen"); }
    function windowCountChanged(){ document.getElementById("countSpan").textContent = windowCount; }
    function windowListChanged(){ document.getElementById("listSpan").textContent = otherWindowIDList.join(", "); }
    function setActiveClick(){ if (setWindowActive) setWindowActive(); }
    function longOperationClick(){ var s = "", start = Date.now(); while (Date.now()<(start+10000)) { s += Math.sin(Math.random()*9999999).toString; s = s.substring(s.length>>>1); } return !!s; }
    window.addEventListener("unload",function(){window.isUnloading = true});
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){window.DOMContentLoadedDone = true});
  </script>
  <style>
    body {padding:40px}
    span {padding-left:40px;color:darkblue}
    input {margin:100px 60px}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   This Window's ID: <span id="idSpan">???</span><br><br>
   Active Window ID: <span id="activeSpan">???</span><br><br>
   Window Count: <span id="countSpan">???</span><br><br>
   Other Window IDs: <span id="listSpan">???</span><br><br>
   <div>
     <input type="button" value="Set This Window Active" onclick="setActiveClick()">
     <input type="button" value="Perform 10-second blocking computation" onclick="longOperationClick()">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**sharedworker-host.js**

```
{ // this block is just to trap 'let' variables inside
  let port = (new SharedWorker("sharedworker.js")).port;
  var thisWindowID = 0, activeWindowID = 0, windowIsConnected = false, windowIsActive = false, windowCount = 0, otherWindowIDList = [];

  //function windowConnected(){}         //
  //function windowDisconnected(){}      //
  //function activeWindowChanged(){}     // do something when changes happen... these need to be implemented in another file (e.g. in the html in an inline <script> tag)
  //function windowCountChanged(){}      //
  //function windowListChanged(){}       //

  function setWindowActive() { if (thisWindowID) port.postMessage("setActive"); }
  function sortedArrayInsert(arr,val) { var a = 0, b = arr.length, m, v; if (!b) arr.push(val); else { while (a<b) if (arr[m = ((a+b)>>>1)]<val) a = m+1; else b = m; if (arr[a]!==val) arr.splice(a,0,val); }}
  function sortedArrayDelete(arr,val) { var a = 0, b = arr.length, m, v; if (b) { while (a<b) if (arr[m = ((a+b)>>>1)]<val) a = m+1; else b = m; if (arr[a]===val) arr.splice(a,1); }}

  let msgHandler = function(e)
  {
    var data = e.data, msg = data[0];
    if (!(windowIsConnected||(msg==="setID")||(msg==="disconnected"))) { windowIsConnected = true; windowConnected(false); }
    switch (msg)
    {
      case "ping": port.postMessage("pong"); break;
      case "setID": thisWindowID = data[1]; windowConnected(windowIsConnected = true); break;
      case "setActive": if (activeWindowID!==(activeWindowID = data[1])) { windowIsActive = (thisWindowID===activeWindowID); activeWindowChanged(); } break;
      case "disconnected": port.postMessage("pong"); windowIsConnected = windowIsActive = false; if (thisWindowID===activeWindowID) { activeWindowID = 0; activeWindowChanged(); } windowDisconnected(); break;
    // THE REST ARE OPTIONAL:
      case "windowCount": if (windowCount!==(windowCount = data[1])) windowCountChanged(); break;
      case "existing": otherWindowIDList = data[1].sort((a,b) => a-b); windowListChanged(); break;
      case "opened": sortedArrayInsert(otherWindowIDList,data[1]); windowListChanged(); break;
      case "closed": sortedArrayDelete(otherWindowIDList,data[1]); windowListChanged(); break;
    }
  };

  if (!window.isUnloading)
  {
    if (window.DOMContentLoadedDone) port.onmessage = msgHandler; else window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){port.onmessage = msgHandler});
    window.addEventListener("unload",function(){port.postMessage("close")});
  }
}
```

**sharedworker.js**

```
// This shared worker:
// (a) Provides each window with a unique ID (note that this can change if a window reconnects due to an inactivity timeout)
// (b) Maintains a list and a count of open windows
// (c) Maintains a single "active" window, and keeps all connected windows apprised of which window that is
//
// It needs to RECEIVE simple string-only messages:
//   "close" - when a window is closing
//   "setActive" - when a window wants to be set to be the active window
//   "pong" (or in fact ANY message at all other than "close") - must be received as a reply to ["ping"], or within (2 x pingTimeout) milliseconds of the last recived message, or the window will be considered closed/crashed/hung
//
// It will SEND messages:
//   ["setID",<unique window ID>] - when a window connects, it will receive it's own unique ID via this message (this must be remembered by the window)
//   ["setActive",<active window ID>] - when a window connects or reconnects, or whenever the active window changes,  it will receive the ID of the "active" window via this message (it can compare to it's own ID to tell if it's the active window)
//   ["ping"] - a window sent this message should send back a "pong" message (or actually ANY message except "close") to confirm it's still alive
//   ["disconnected"] - when a window is disconnected due to a ping timeout, it'll recieve this message; assuming it hasn't closed it should immediately send a "pong", in order to reconnect.
// AND OPTIONALLY (REMOVE lines noted in comments to disable):
// IF EACH WINDOW NEEDS (ONLY) A RUNNING COUNT OF TOTAL CONNECTED WINDOWS:
//   ["windowCount",<count of connected windows>] - sent to a window on connection or reconnection, and whenever the window count changes
// OR ALTERNATIVELY, IF EACH WINDOW NEEDS A COMPLETE LIST OF THE IDs OF ALL OTHER WINDOWS:
//   ["existing",<array of existing window IDs>] - sent upon connectionor reconnection
//   ["opened",<ID of just-opened window>] - sent to all OTHER windows, when a window connects or reconnects
//   ["closed",<ID of closing window>] - sent to all OTHER windows, when a window disconnects (either because it explicitly sent a "close" message, or because it's been too long since its last message (> pingTimeout))

const pingTimeout = 1000;  // milliseconds
var count = 0, lastID = 0, activeID = 0, allPorts = {};

function handleMessage(e)
{
  var port = this, msg = e.data;
  if (port.pingTimeoutID) { clearTimeout(port.pingTimeoutID); port.pingTimeoutID = 0; }
  if (msg==="close") portClosed(port,false); else
  {
    if (!allPorts[port.uniqueID]) connectPort(port,false);  // reconnect disconnected port
    if (msg==="setActive") setActive(port.uniqueID);
    port.pingTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){pingPort(port)},pingTimeout);
  }
}

function setActive(portID)  // if portID is 0, this actually sets the active port ID to the first port in allPorts{} if present (or 0 if no ports are connected)
{
  if (activeID!==portID)
  {
    activeID = portID;
    for(var pID in allPorts) if (allPorts.hasOwnProperty(pID)) allPorts[pID].postMessage(["setActive",(activeID||(activeID = +pID))]);
  }
}

function pingPort(port)
{
  port.postMessage(["ping"]);
  port.pingTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){portClosed(port,true)},pingTimeout);
}

function portClosed(port,fromTimeout)
{
  var portID = port.uniqueID;
  if (fromTimeout) port.postMessage(["disconnected"]); else { clearTimeout(port.pingTimeoutID); port.close(); }
  port.pingTimeoutID = 0;
  if (allPorts[portID])
  {
    delete allPorts[portID];
    --count;
    if (activeID===portID) setActive(0);
    for(var pID in allPorts) if (allPorts.hasOwnProperty(pID)) allPorts[pID].postMessage(["closed",portID]);  // REMOVE if windows don't need a list of all other window IDs
    for(var pID in allPorts) if (allPorts.hasOwnProperty(pID)) allPorts[pID].postMessage(["windowCount",count]);  // REMOVE if change of window-count doesn't need to be broadcast to all windows
  }
}

function newConnection(e)
{
  var port = e.source;
  port.uniqueID = ++lastID;
  port.onmessage = handleMessage;
  connectPort(port,true);
}

function connectPort(port,initialConnection)
{
  var portID = port.uniqueID;
  port.postMessage(["existing",Object.keys(allPorts).map(x => +x)]);for(var pID in allPorts) if (allPorts.hasOwnProperty(pID)) allPorts[pID].postMessage(["opened",portID]);  // REMOVE if windows don't need a list of all other window IDs
  allPorts[portID] = port;
  ++count;
  for(var pID in allPorts) if (allPorts.hasOwnProperty(pID)) allPorts[pID].postMessage(["windowCount",count]);  // REMOVE if change of window-count doesn't need to be broadcast to all windows
  if (initialConnection) { port.postMessage(["setID",lastID]); port.pingTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){pingPort(port)},pingTimeout); }
  if (!activeID) setActive(portID); else port.postMessage(["setActive",activeID]);
}

onconnect = newConnection;
```