# Javascript; list all same-origin windows/tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, webkit, chromium

The goal is to have a window/tab have the list of its sibling windows/tabs having the same domain.

My first attempts with SharedWorker failed, see [JavaScript: How to know if a connection with a shared worker is still alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662089/javascript-how-to-know-if-a-connection-with-a-shared-worker-is-still-alive)

A Webkit only solution would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use localStorage, which is per-domain. Have the tabs register themselves with some unique ID as the localStorage key, and delete that entry on unload.

Comment: Yeah, but if a tab crashes or hangs (or the browser itself hangs, or its process is forcibly killed, or the computer powers down unexpectedly, etc) it won't delete it's localStorage entry, which will then stick around forever...